# I can't run in terminal npm run build

Tags: runtime-error, node-modules, vite, rollup

I want to run on the Terminal using npm run build and it's get error.

```
$ npm run build

webkelas@0.0.0 build
vite build

vite v4.4.11 building for production...

/assets/index-389f154d.css doesn't exist at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime
2 moduls transformed.
built in 1.95s
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/assets/index-c42d0bed.js" from "/w orkspaces/Web-Kelas-V2/index.html".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runt ime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to build.rollupOptions.external
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/assets/index-c42d0bed.js" f rom "/workspaces/Web-Kelas-V2/index.html".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runt ime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to build.rollupOptions.external
at viteWarn (file:///workspaces/Web-Kelas-V2/node_modules/vite/dist/node
/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:48205:27)
at onwarn (file:///workspaces/Web-Kelas-V2/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-r
eact/dist/index.mjs:247:9)
at onRollupWarning (file:///workspaces/Web-Kelas-V2/node_modules/vite/di st/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:48234:9)
at onwarn (file:///workspaces/Web-Kelas-V2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/c
hunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:47965:13)
at file:///workspaces/Web-Kelas-V2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/no
de-entry.js:24276:13
at Object.logger [as onLog] (file:///workspaces/Web-Kelas-V2/node_module s/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25950:9)
at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///workspaces/Web-Kelas-V2 /node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24862:26)
at file:///workspaces/Web-Kelas-V2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/no
de-entry.js:24822:26
```

I tried Update the vite, install the vite again, using `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`, checking the `package.json`, install again node.js and the result its all the same in github, nothing changed.